# Summing absolute values in for loop - python

Tags: python, list, for-loop, sum

I am trying to sum the absolute value of the difference between two lists. The difference between xRatings and yRatings. Here the ideal result is 22.5

Here is my code.I feel like the fix is simple, but i'm just not seeing it. Any suggestions?

```
import math

xRatings =[1,5,1,3.5,4,4,3]
yRatings = [5,1,5,1,1,1,1]
sum_= 0

for i in range(7):

    count = [math.fabs(xRatings[i]-yRatings[i])]
    sum_ += i

return sum_


print(sum_)
```

Comment: `sum_ += count`, not `sum_ += i`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

`print(sum(abs(x-y) for (x, y) in zip(xRatings, yRatings)))`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
sum( abs(xRatings[i] - yRatings[i]) for i in range(len(xRatings)))
```

It's a pythonic one-liner, reasonably efficient and concise.

Comment: `zip()` would probably be more pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Using your method:

```
import math

xRatings =[1,5,1,3.5,4,4,3]
yRatings = [5,1,5,1,1,1,1]
sum_= 0

for i in range(7):

    count = math.fabs(xRatings[i]-yRatings[i])
    sum_ += count

print(sum_)
```

`count` should be an `int`, not a `list`, you needed to add `count` to `sum_`, not `i`, and `return` is used inside functions, and so is unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

This works as Python 2.7:

```
xRatings =[1,5,1,3.5,4,4,3]
yRatings = [5,1,5,1,1,1,1]
sum_= 0

for i in range(7):
    sum_ += abs(xRatings[i]-yRatings[i])

print sum_
```